# Failed to start Vuforia on Unity UWP executable build

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, build, vuforia

I'm trying to build a very simple UWP app (for PC Desktop only) with a single image target and camera using Vuforia on Unity.
Everything works fine in the Editor, but after I build and run the app I get the following error on a black screen :
[image]

I don't even know where to debug this, as the only log I get is this error and nothing else. I also tried delayed initialization, but this same behavior happens when I manually call `VuforiaAppllication.Instance.Initialize();` after it's initialized and before it's started.
Here's my build settings :
[image]

I'm using `Unity 2020.3.30f1` and `Vuforia 10.2.5`, the only target SDK installed on my system is `10.0.19041.0` and also, I have `Visual Studio 2019 Community` installed if that info helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by disabling my laptop's webcam from device manager, and connecting an external USB camera.